# I wanted to create an apk while applying with flutter and I get this error

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to create an apk while applying with flutter and I get this error. While trying to solve the error, I deleted a few files. How can I fix this problem?

This is the error I get:

[image]

I updated the gradle file of the application, but the error was still not resolved.

Comment: have you read this !!!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: update your question please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could attempt updating Flutter to the latest version as it might gradle error.  and also update android studio version